# C# Console Application can't load file or assembly, but needs a dll which doesn't exists?

Tags: assembly, .net, c#, error

I have a strange error. I created for testing purposes a normal Console Application and run my own Tracer which is written with the help of Mono.Cecil on this application. I embedd a Stopwatch at the entry and exit of every method.

After I embedd it (the IL doesn't have any errors or warnings in it, when I inspect it with ILSpy) and try to run the Console Application it throws:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly   'System.Runtime
> .Extensions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its depende
> ncies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Which is really strange, because Version = 4.2.2.0 doesn't even exists? Does anybody have a idea how this could be solved?

So when I try to give that Application any other Version of System.Runtime.Extensions this is thrown:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Ext
> ensions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencie
> s. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm stuck and would be thankful for every help or idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: this looks very similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878602/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-x-or-one-of-i

Comment: Is your problem with the non-existing version or the reference itself? `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` resides in `System.Runtime.Extensions` for .net core so I guess it makes sense that the app tries to load it.

Comment: The main problem is the version it asks, because version=4.2.2.0 doesn't even exists. I have no idea why it would ask me for this kind of version. I could solve it a little bit with Mono.Cecil, by loading System.Runtime.Extensions and change the Version to '4.2.2.0'. But I think it is not a good idea to do it this way.